# why laravel ajax returns json view page

Tags: ajax, laravel

i am using ajax to store the info but when i store or not store it returns a json page and i don't want it to return a json i want to add the item without relead the page and using calidation also
please help
here is my code

my route

```
Route::resource('products',App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class);
```

my form

```
<form method="POST" id="productform">
        @csrf
        @method('POST')
        <ul id="showerrors">

        </ul>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

and my ajax code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    

    $('#productform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        'name' : $("input[name='name']").val(),
        '_token' : $("input[name='token']").val(),
    }
    // console.log(data);
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
        $.ajax({ 
            url:"/products",
            type : "POST",
            data:data,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response.status);
                if(response.status == 400){
                    $('#showerrors').empty();   
                    $('#showerrors').addClass('alert alert-danger');
                    $.each(response.errors,function(key,value){
                        $('#showerrors').append('<li>'+value+'</li>')
                    });
                }
                else{
                    $("#successmessage").empty();
                    $("#successmessage").addClass('alert alert-success');
                    $("#successmessage").text(response.message);
                    $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle'); //or  $('#IDModal').modal('hide');
                    conssole.log(response.message);
                    return false;
                }
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean with "returns json view page". Please elaborate

Comment: Show Your controller

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

add id to input field

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
```

changes in script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#productform').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var name = $('#name').val();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url:"/products",
            type : "POST",
            data:{
                name: name
            },
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response.status);
                if(response.status == 400){
                    $('#showerrors').empty();
                    $('#showerrors').addClass('alert alert-danger');
                    $.each(response.errors,function(key,value){
                        $('#showerrors').append('<li>'+value+'</li>')
                    });
                }
                else{
                    $("#successmessage").empty();
                    $("#successmessage").addClass('alert alert-success');
                    $("#successmessage").text(response.message);
                    $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle'); //or  $('#IDModal').modal('hide');
                    conssole.log(response.message);
                    return false;
                }
            },
        });
    });
});
```

in your controller store function

*suppose your model name is Product*

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    ...

    $product = Product::create($request->only('name));

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 200,
        'message' => 'Product created successfully.'
    ]);
}
```